# how to check if image is selected?

Tags: android, view, imageview

is there any way in which i have a image view which has to change its state/view once pressed and remain in its state and I should be able to check its state whether it was pressed or is in pressed state right now or not? i used android:pressed but in that case the image state changes until it remains pressed and back to default when no pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can Have a `onClickListener` to check whether the image is selected.. U can maintain a state using a `boolean` variable there.. Try the below code...

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);    
imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if(v.equals(imageView)){
                 /* Make selected if user clicks and maintain the state urself*/
            }
 }
```

Comment: is there any other method of handling selected/unselected states with ImageView? This thing will obviously work but it will be more somehow cumbersome to apply.

Comment: @usman: Sorry, I dint used that thing till now.. but there is `imageView.isSelected()` method u can make use of it i think. But dont know exactly. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isSelected%28%29

Comment: for now, i am doing this, but there must be another way to this instead of just manually setting selected to true or false  italic bold code ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { if(imageView.isSelected()){ imageView.setSelected(false);}else{ imageView.setSelected(true);

Comment: @UsmanL Maybe, I will suggest if i come across about it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set up a ClickListener on the image, although I never tried it.

Comment: is there any other method of handling selected/unselected states with ImageView? This thing will obviously work but it will be more somehow cumbersome to apply.

Comment: Does this work? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isSelected()

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
boolean img_visible = true;//(If image's visibility is set to true in xml file else false)
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if(imageView.getVisibility()==ImageView.VISIBLE||img_visible){
               imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
               img_visible = false;
           }
           else
           {
               imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
               img_visible = true;
           }
             }
      }
```

Comment: for now, i am doing this, but there must be another way to this _italic_ **bold** `code`     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); 

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { if(imageView.isSelected()){ imageView.setSelected(false);}else{ imageView.setSelected(true);